# Changing from Test ad ID to real value for AdMob through

Tags: android, firebase, google-ads-api, admob

I am developing an Android application and have integrated AdMob through Firebase as described on

https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start
and
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner

Now, using their test ad id such as

> adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111");

Everything works fine, and I can see their dummy-content. However, I need to change this before building final apk before release. But my question is, and I've tried to find the answer in both firebase docs and adword docs, can I use the app myself, and how can I make sure the content is real ad content (starting the app myself) without being afraid to get banned from the ad system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run it on Emulator, add emulator as test device

```
AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder()
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR) 
.build();
```

Elsewere if you run it on real device, add it as a test device like this :

```
 .addTestDevice(“YOUR DEVICE ID”)
```

To get your device ID, run your app on a real device and when AdRequest is built, go to logcat and filter by `AdRequest`, you will say something like

> this I/Ads(....): To get test ads on this device, call
>   adRequest.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");"

Then copy and past the code to add it to your adrequest and it will be done

Comment: Oh, so you mean that I kind of "whitelist" my own devices and emulators for ever and ever?

Comment: Yes you can add lot of real devices

Comment: thank you! Can I keep my added test devices even for release, so that if I install my app from Google play, I won't be shown real ads? Also,

Comment: Yes of course, if you install your app from google play store you keep getting test ads on registred devices

Comment: E.Abdel, wierd. After publishing my app from google play store and installing it from there, I get real ads without the label "test ad".

Comment: strange, in my add it's showing, what is the SDK version that you use?

Comment: I have 26 (8.0.0) on my device.. is it safe to use the app as long as I dont click banners and interstitials?